# How can I compare 2 values from different elements and take action ONLY for elements that have matching values?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm almost finished with a script that'll search multiple elements to look for a person's name.  If the script finds a match, it SHOULD grab an ID value in that element for ONLY the elements that contain a person's name.

After that, this script should search for a different group of elements, and find their input values.  If the input values match the ID values from the previous elements, I'd like to have it change the background color for a child element that shares the same parent as the ones with input values.

**Expected outcome**: Essentially: Let's say I have 3 items, but only 2 contain the word "Rufio". For only the items that contain "Rufio", those items should have their background color changed.

**Current outcome**: Instead of changing the background color only for elements that contain "Rufio", the script is currently changing the color for ALL elements.

I'm sure I've got myself lost in all my brackets here, but where am I going wrong?

```
var checkexist = setInterval(function() {
  var tickets = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=ticket-tip-] > div > ul > li");

  tickets.forEach(ticket => {
    if (ticket.innerHTML.indexOf("Rufio") !== -1) {
      var ticketid = ticket.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
      var fancyID = ticketid.replace("ticket-tip-", "");
      var mainareas = document.querySelectorAll(
        "[id^=player-ticket-content] > div.ticket-holder > div > ul > li > input"
      );
      var tickethrefs = document.querySelectorAll(
        "[id^=player-ticket-content] > div.ticket-holder > div > ul > li > a"
      );

      mainareas.forEach(mainarea => {
        tickethrefs.forEach(tickethref => {
          if ((mainarea.value = fancyID)) {
            tickethref.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff66";
            console.log(mainarea.value);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
  clearInterval(checkexist);
}, 7000);
```

---

**EDITED**

HTML snippet below:

```html
<div id="player-ticket-content">
  <button class="btn btn-small" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">Merge</button>
  <div class="loading" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
    <div class="spinner dotted"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ticket-holder" style="display: block;">
    <div class="tooltip-holder">
      <ul class="tickets " style="display: block; max-height: 90px; opacity: 1;">

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="40070921" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://company.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/40070921" id="ticket-40070921"> <span class="ticket_status_label solved">solved</span> <span class="similarity" title="Similarity of ticket tags" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">                <i class="icon-star"></i>        </span> <span class="subject"><span>hello?</span></span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="39711568" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://company.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/39711568" id="ticket-39711568"> <span class="ticket_status_label closed">closed</span> <span class="similarity" title="Similarity of ticket tags" style="background-color: rgb(255, 174, 174);">                78%        </span> <span class="subject"><span>hello again!</span></span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="21875024" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://company.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/21875024" id="ticket-21875024"> <span class="ticket_status_label closed">closed</span> <span class="similarity" title="Similarity of ticket tags" style="background-color: rgb(255, 241, 241);">                44%        </span> <span class="subject"><span>woop woop</span></span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-40070921" style="top: 24px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> Apr 22, 2019</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Rufio</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>test!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-39711568" style="top: 48px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> Mar 26, 2019</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Rufio</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>hello hello!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-21875024" style="top: 72px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> May 28, 2016</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Robert</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>It's me again!

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(mainarea.value = fancyID)` is an assignment. What you want is a comparison. Use `(mainarea.value === fancyID)`. Plus, you're not considering whether `tickethref.id` actually is matching `fancyID`, which just colors all `tickethref`s.

You need to change the if condition

```
if ((mainarea.value === fancyID && tickethref.id.includes(fancyID))) {
    tickethref.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff66";
    console.log(mainarea.value);
}
```

```js
var checkexist = setInterval(function() {
  var tickets = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=ticket-tip-] > div > ul > li");

  tickets.forEach(ticket => {
    if (ticket.innerHTML.indexOf("Rufio") !== -1) {
      var ticketid = ticket.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
      var fancyID = ticketid.replace("ticket-tip-", "");
      var mainareas = document.querySelectorAll(
        "[id^=player-ticket-content] > div.ticket-holder > div > ul > li > input"
      );
      var tickethrefs = document.querySelectorAll(
        "[id^=player-ticket-content] > div.ticket-holder > div > ul > li > a"
      );
      mainareas.forEach(mainarea => {
        tickethrefs.forEach(tickethref => {
          if ((mainarea.value === fancyID && tickethref.id.includes(fancyID))) {
            tickethref.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff66";
            console.log(mainarea.value);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
  clearInterval(checkexist);
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="player-ticket-content">


  <div class="ticket-holder" style="display: block;">
    <div class="tooltip-holder">
      <ul class="tickets " style="display: block; max-height: 90px; opacity: 1;">

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="40070921" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://companyname.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/40070921" id="ticket-40070921"> <span class="ticket_status_label solved">solved</span> </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="39711568" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://companyname.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/39711568" id="ticket-39711568"> <span class="ticket_status_label closed">closed</span> </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="21875024" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://company.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/21875024" id="ticket-21875024"> <span class="ticket_status_label closed">closed</span> <span class="similarity" title="Similarity of ticket tags" style="background-color: rgb(255, 241, 241);">                44%        </span> <span class="subject"><span>text here!</span></span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-40070921" style="top: 22px; left: 3px; display: none;">
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> Apr 22, 2019</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Rufio </li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>text here!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-39711568" style="top: 26px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> Mar 26, 2019</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Rufio</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>more text!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-21875024" style="top: 50px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> May 28, 2016</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Robert</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Oh hey, text!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I feel your for loops are unnecessary. If you're working with ids, they are supposed to be unique. I've modified it to make it much more simpler. See the `tickethref` selector.

```js
var checkexist = setInterval(function() {
  var tickets = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=ticket-tip-] > div > ul > li");

  tickets.forEach(ticket => {
    if (ticket.innerHTML.indexOf("Rufio") !== -1) {
      var ticketid = ticket.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
      var fancyID = ticketid.replace("ticket-tip-", "");
      var tickethref = document.querySelector(
        `[id^=player-ticket-content] > div.ticket-holder > div > ul > li > a[id=ticket-${fancyID}]`
      );
      if (tickethref) {
        tickethref.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff66";
      }
    }
  });
  clearInterval(checkexist);
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="player-ticket-content">


  <div class="ticket-holder" style="display: block;">
    <div class="tooltip-holder">
      <ul class="tickets " style="display: block; max-height: 90px; opacity: 1;">

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="40070921" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://companyname.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/40070921" id="ticket-40070921"> <span class="ticket_status_label solved">solved</span> </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="39711568" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://companyname.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/39711568" id="ticket-39711568"> <span class="ticket_status_label closed">closed</span> </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ticket[]" value="21875024" disabled="disabled">
          <a class="ticket zd" href="https://company.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/21875024" id="ticket-21875024"> <span class="ticket_status_label closed">closed</span> <span class="similarity" title="Similarity of ticket tags" style="background-color: rgb(255, 241, 241);">                44%        </span> <span class="subject"><span>text here!</span></span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-40070921" style="top: 22px; left: 3px; display: none;">
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> Apr 22, 2019</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Rufio </li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>text here!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-39711568" style="top: 26px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> Mar 26, 2019</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Rufio</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>more text!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-tip" id="ticket-tip-21875024" style="top: 50px; left: 3px; display: none;"> <span class="nub"><span></span></span>
        <div class="comment">
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Date:</strong> May 28, 2016</li>
            <li><strong>Assignee:</strong> Robert</li>
            <li><strong>Requester:</strong> Customer</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Oh hey, text!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the heads up! Sadly even after replacing that comparison, the script is changing the background color for all elements instead of ones containing "Rufio".  Should I turn `ticket.innerHTML.indexOf("Rufio") !== -1` into a variable, and then include it in a `forEach` statement?

Comment: Please share your HTML in the question. It's hard to answer without that.

Comment: Sure thing! Here's where we're up against a few barriers: I'm currently doing this Javascript work through a Tampermonkey script, since I sadly don't have access to making HTML changes.   Some of the HTML content contains sensitive information as well.

Getting the HTML itself ended up looking messy, so I did my best to show only the essential elements through a screenshot with Chrome's Inspector view.  If there's anything more you need, please let me know. Thanks again, Maaz.

Comment: Unfortunately screenshots are not very helpful to reproduce a problem. Please type in as much HTML required to reproduce the problem with the current JS in the question. Create a stack snippet if possible (You can do so by clicking the `[<>]` icon when editing your question)

Comment: Thank you again!  I've created the HTML snippet as requested, and edited into the end of my question. Please let me know if there's anything more I can do to help.

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you so much!! I'm a big fan of your `tickethref` selector changes, and I didn't even know you could select an element based off a wildcard element like with `${fancyID}`, neat! Your shorter code also calls those `tickethref` elements ONLY when they meet the conditions, compared to mine where I'm assigning variables to just about everything. I have so much to learn yet, so thank you for calling out bad habits of mine.b

Comment: You're welcome. Don't be too hard on yourself. Your code was almost working. Your existing solution would also work given the changes I've suggested. Remember to make stuff work, before thinking of optimisations/alternatives. All the best!